# what would be the lambda syntax of this instead of reference syntax?

Tags: java

I am confused in this line:

```
 todoRepository.findAll().forEach(todos::add);
```

what would be the lambda format of this without using reference syntax.

Comment: `forEach(el -> todos.add(el));`

Comment: Why would you need to add _all_ the todos returned by a repository to some new collection `todos`?  Assuming `TodoRepository::findAll` returns a `Collection<Todo>`, a new list can be created as: `List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>(todoRepo.findAll());`  If domain `Todo` objects need to be remapped to some DTO, Stream API should be used in a different way: `List<TodoDto> todos = todoRepo.findAll().stream().map(TodoDto::new).collect(Collectors.toList());` (or if a separate mapper exists: `.map(TodoMapper::toDto)`)

Answer (score 1):

`todoRepository.findAll().forEach(todo -> todos.add(todo));`

The `todos::add` is just a shortcut for calling `todos.add`